# SAS OLEDB connection and Teradata Volatile table

Tags: sql, database, sas, teradata, proc

I have some SAS developers who do not have [SAS access for Teradata Installed](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/teradata.pdf)

and they are not on SAS query  grid . Instead they use OLEDB to connect to Teradata. 
OLEDB does not seem to like create volatile table statement. Has anyone had some luck using it and get VT's in teradata to work

This is what's installed on the SAS W2K serveer

```
     proc setinit; run;


  ---Base SAS Software
            30DEC2016
    ---SAS/STAT
            30DEC2016
    ---SAS/GRAPH
            30DEC2016
    ---SAS/Secure 168-bit
            30DEC2016
    ---SAS/Secure Windows
            30DEC2016
    ---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files
            30DEC2016
    ---SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC
            30DEC2016
    ---SAS/ACCESS Interface to OLE DB
            30DEC2016
    ---SAS Workspace Server for Local Access
            30DEC2016
    ---High Performance Suite
            30DEC2016
```

I can see ODBC but I not sure.. is that supposed to mean ODBC driver for TD and how to use is instead of OLEDB ?

```
(create multiset volatile table VT (C1 integer, C2 date))
```

The above test code fails with message that it expects a column name on a create table statement. The extra R & L Parenthesis is because this is embedded in SAS 
but if I remove the `Volatile` statement , it will  run fine.

Here is the detailed error

```
    proc sql;
  connect to OLEDB(Provider='MSDASQL' Extended_Properties='DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=SITEPRD;AUTHENTICATION=ldap' UID="&DMID" PWD="&DMPWD");
  execute (create multiset volatile table idlist (my_id integer, mydate date)
  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS) by teradata;
  execute (COMMIT WORK) by teradata;
  insert into idlist
  select distinct MyId_sas, mydate
  from mysource;
quit; 3:52 PM 
And got this output: 3:52 PM 
proc sql;
28     connect to OLEDB(Provider='MSDASQL' Extended_Properties='DRIVER={Teradata};
28 ! DBCNAME=SITEPRD;AUTHENTICATION=ldap' UID="&DMID" PWD="&DMPWD");
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DMID resolves to ConfusedUser
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DMPWD resolves to Youbetcha!

29     execute (create multiset volatile table idlist (my_id integer, mydate date)
30     ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS) by teradata;
ERROR: The TERADATA engine cannot be found.
ERROR: A Connection to the teradata DBMS is not currently supported, or is not installed at
       your site.
31     execute (COMMIT WORK) by teradata;
ERROR: The TERADATA engine cannot be found.
ERROR: A Connection to the teradata DBMS is not currently supported, or is not installed at
       your site.
32     insert into idlist
33     select distinct MyId_sas, mydate
34     from mysource;
ERROR: File WORK.idlist.DATA does not exist.
NOTE: SGIO processing active for file WORK.mysource.DATA.
35   quit;
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           9.19 seconds
      cpu time            1.75 seconds
```

Comment: Can you share the log from the failed execution?

Comment: Post the full code. That's just a snippet. If you used proc sql it would not work, if you want to use Teradata options you need to pass the query to Teradata via SQL Pass through.

Comment: Also, `proc setinit` shows what's licensed, not what's installed. `proc product_status` shows what's installed.

Comment: Hi Rob and Reeza. TY - I added the error log above